# Firebase cloud function cannot upload simple txt file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying to upload a simple test file from my working directory to firebase storage. To do so i created this code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

 exports.Storage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {


const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');

const options = {
  destination: 'Test_Folder/hello_world.dog'
};
bucket.upload('./tst.txt', options).then(function(data) {
  const file = data[0];
  if (file) {
      return file;
  }else{
    throw new Error("Irgendwas geht ned")
}
}).catch(e);
return 200;
});
```

Unfortunately firebase is always saying:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tst.txt'

My File is located in ./tst.txt in my project
My Goal is to generate a text file inside my cloudfunction and upload them to firebase storage to store it. No files are currently stored in storage. Now i want to be able to upload a file which is already created.
This is how my files are organized:
[image: Filetree]

Comment: Please edit the question to describe more clearly how your project is structured.  We need to be able to see where the files actually are.  There should be enough information here so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: i edited it, hope you are now able to understand my problem and give me some hints to fix it. Thanks for your annotation

Comment: That didn't really help.  We need to understand how your files are organized on disk to see how you are deploying tst.txt, or even if it's being deployed.

Comment: @DougStevenson i hope the screenshot helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will deploy all of the files in the functions folder, except for node_modules.  Your tst.txt file isn't in there - it's one folder higher.  So it's not even being deployed.  You will have to move it into functions in order to make it available to the function at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up here with a `requirements.txt` file not uploading issue (python). It was because the `.gcloudignore` had `.git` & `.gitignore` in it, but I had a `*.txt` inside my `.gitignore` file. I removed the `*.txt` from `.gitignore` then it worked.